# Changing positional arguments passed to the command "srun"

Tags: lua, slurm, lua-table

I am trying to implement the below lua script in cli_filer/lua. This script is designed to force bash to treat all interactive session as login sessions (e.g. source /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/*.sh).
But setting a new value or replacing the existing value of "bash" to "bash -l" doesn't seem to work.

```lua
function slurm_cli_pre_submit(options, pack_offset)
    if options["type"] == "srun" then
        if options["pty"] ~= nil then
            if options.argv[1] == "bash" then
                options.argv[1] = 'bash --login'          <<
                print(options.argv[1])                    <<
                print("slurm_cli_pre_submit: Forcing interactive non-login session as a login shell with -l")
            end
        end
    end
    return slurm.SUCCESS
end

function slurm_cli_setup_defaults(options, early_pass)
    return slurm.SUCCESS
end

function slurm_cli_post_submit(offset, job_id, step_id)
    return slurm.SUCCESS
end
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.2$ srun -w node5 --pty bash
bash                                      <<
slurm_cli_pre_submit: Forcing interactive non-login session as a login shell with -l
bash-4.4$
```

Comment: I have no clue about lua but I think you should put the extra argument in its own parameter, something like: `options.argv[2] = "--login"`.

Comment: Check your ```options```. Is it the whole string ```"-w node5 --pty bash"```? Then you have to check ```if  options:sub(-4, -1) == "bash"```

Comment: If not, provide us the datatype of options and its exact content (key/value pairs if it is a table). And i am corious: What is ```slurm.SUCCESS``` and where it comes from?

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi This question is tagged with [`slurm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slurm), and is discussing the [cli_filter Plugin API](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cli_filter_plugins.html). AFAICT, `slurm.SUCCESS` seems to be set [here](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/lua/slurm_lua.c#L238), and the plugin is presumably managed [here](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/plugins/cli_filter/lua/cli_filter_lua.c). If I'm not mistaken, `options` is a table (an empty one, that enables an interface via its metatable and metamethods).

Comment: I have no experience with Slurm, but digging around in the source code (after finding the documentation lacking) would suggest `options.argv` is a [transient construction](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/plugins/cli_filter/lua/cli_filter_lua.c#L244), that returns a [copy of program arguments](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/plugins/cli_filter/lua/cli_filter_lua.c#L165). Unless I'm missing something (not unlikely), assignment to this table (e.g., `options.argv[2] = "--login"`) does not appear to propagate in any way.

Comment: The other thought was something like `options['login'] = true`, but that seems to be the [interface](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/plugins/cli_filter/lua/cli_filter_lua.c#L294) for [setting predefined options](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/common/slurm_opt.c#L5801)(?). Hopefully someone with some experience with this tool can offer more insight.

Comment: You can count ```options.argv``` with ```#options.argv``` and with a loop you can output its content: ```for i = 1, #options.argv do print(i, options.argv[i]) end``` this should tell you which key (```i```) is: ```bash```